# Is there a SecurityCenter2 namespace equivalent on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: c#, namespaces, wmi, windows-server-2019

I am writing a C# application that, among other things, gathers status information about Windows Defender. On Windows 10, using `ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Root\SecurityCenter2", "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct")` works fine to get some initial information (e.g., Windows Defender is installed, is enabled, and is up-to-date), but on Windows Server 2019, I take an invalid namespace exception on `Root\SecurityCenter2`.

Using PowerShell and

```
Get-WMIObject -namespace "root" -class "__Namespace" | Select Name
```

I've browsed through the WMI namespaces on Windows Server 2019, but don't see anything that jumps out at me as an equivalent/newer version of the `SecurityCenter2` namespace. If I just assume that Windows Defender is installed and enabled, I can successfully gather other required details in the `Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender` namespace just fine. But I'd prefer to be able to check the general status of Windows Defender beforehand, using the `AntiVirusProduct` class.

Is there an alternative namespace to `SecurityCenter2` that can be used for performing this initial WMI query on Windows Server 2019?